# AutoCompleteBox max number of results

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

I'm using wpf toolkit AutoCompleteBox control and I want it to display only 5 results, How can I set this ?

I've noticed that there's a Property called "MaxDropDownHeight" but it doesn't help since more than 5 results are displayed but with scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `ItemFilter` to a delegate of type...

```
public AutoCompleteFilterPredicate<Object> ItemFilter { get; set; }
```

...doing this will also default the `FilterMode` to `Custom`. An example is located on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.itemfilter%28VS.95%29.aspx) site.

Once you have the base functionality implemented you will need to keep a class level count so that you can return N values since the filter will be called once for each item.

Thus by setting your class level count to 5; once you hit the 6 you could return false within your filter code.

In addition you will need to know when the search criteria has changed so you can begin the filtering process from 0.